# Javascript event handler on list item li parent node

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, html-lists

I'm new to javascript and I wanted to create an event onclick to list items. The problem is that I want to create an event to the li tag, but it keeps firing when I click the descendent ul's.

Here goes part of my code:

```
<li id="1660761" class="HTMLFirstLevel HTMLHorizontalArrowDown">
   <ul id="ul1223945" class="HTMLItem">
       <li id="1490659" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="483463" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="80919" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="1280053" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="1799353" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="1882209" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
       <li id="462917" class="HTMLRemainingLevels"></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li id= ......>
   <ul....>
   <ul...>
</li>
```

and my javascript:

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('1660761');

parentNode.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

    alert('Hi There');

});

}
```

Now I only want it to fire on the item li with the id 1660761, and not the items inside the list.
The list is an imported component and I can't create events inside the html, that's why I'm accessing it outside with javascript.

---

Now here's how I've done it by scaning the div by tag name and then adding a "click" event listener if the content equals the tag inner html that I was searching for.
I leave the rest of the html that it's important to this aproach:

```
<div id="MainMenu" class="HTMLMenuContainer HTMLMenuHorizontal">
    <ul id="ul1351387" class="HTMLMenu">
        <li id="1660761" class="HTMLFirstLevel HTMLHorizontalArrowDown">
            <a href="#">
                <span>Back Office</span>
            </a>
            <ul id="ul1172716" class="HTMLItem">
                <li id="1490659" class="HTMLRemainingLevels">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>

                            Some submenu Here

                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                .....
```

and the code:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('HTMLMenuHorizontal');
var span = divs[0].getElementsByTagName('span');

//I iterate till 19 cause its more than all the spans in the page.
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {

var sp= span[i];

if(sp.innerHTML==('Back Office')){
   sp.addEventListener("click",function back(){
          //do something here like
          alert('Back Office');  
   });  

}
}
```

This works fine and it doesn't fire on the itens inside.
This works because in my case the itens doesn't change the content, only the visibility.
I do the same for all the other itens that have descendents.

Thank you all.

Comment: Thank you all for the help given.
I have solved the problem with a diferent aproach.
Instead of geting the element by id, I scan the div by tag name, untill i find the content that I'm looking for and then add a "click" event listener if the content equals the tag inner html that I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my jQuery code for this problem:

```
$(function(){
    $("li.1660761").live("click", onListItemLink);
}

function onListItemLink(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
```

This one is for JavaScript:

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('1660761');
parentNode.onclick = onListItemLink;

function onListItemLink(){
    alert('Hello World!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this page to undersand correctly:

[capture event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener)

and what's function(e-->??)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#1660761').unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this) return;

    alert('Hey There!');
});
```

Try This code : http://jsfiddle.net/sd5LZ/

Comment: this sample use jquery plugin